# how to write usecase specifcation?

Tags: requirements, use-case

when usecase performed with 2 actors,for example usecase "managment Request" ,that run with Admin and user,and actors do diffrent jobs,for example,in this usecase,admin can "edit Request" and user could not "edit reguest".
how to write usecase specification in this usecase? in fact,could I given "edit Request" for alternative flow?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think it's better to split them into two separate use cases each with a different actor as the use case is supposed to explain only one function of the system. You can though put the "Manage Request" as a parent use case for them both only in case "Manage Request" function has steps of its own. 
And it's not correct to add them as an alternative flow as it's used to show the different outcomes of the function that is resulted from different steps than the basic flow.

Comment: basic flow in manage request(by admin and user),is similar,but "edit request" only do with admin.in this condition,it is better to seprate use cases?

Comment: yes you can in order to prevent confusion, or you can just add it as an alternative flow with a note that this only applies to admin

Comment: add note,I think the best soloution,i consider one usecase and added one note to alternative flow thanx a lot